# Discover devices plugged in via ethernet cables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a controller which I hardwire an ethernet cable into. What I would like to do is find all devices connected via an ethernet cable or something similar and what those devices are. Eg:

```
>>> ???
[{
  host: "192.168.1.4",
  port: 23,
  device: 'Galil DMC-4143'
}]
```

Is this possible to do via python?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It should ideally work on mac, ubuntu, and windows... we're using all three :\

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces). It should help.

Here is example from their documentation:

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']

>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('lo0')
{18: [{'addr': ''}], 2: [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}], 30: [{'peer': '::1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', 'addr': '::1'}, {'peer': '', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::1%lo0'}]}
```

And it should work on OS X, Linux and Windows.